Multiple imputation (MICE)
In my study, I want to examine the association between psychosocial factors and death and calculate the incidence rates of death by the psychosocial factors at baseline. However, some of the psychosocial factors are missing. I plan to use multiple imputation to impute 5 datasets. Is it OK that I average the missing psychosocial factors first (M1+M2+...+M5)/5 and then calculate the incidence rates? Or if I calculate the incidence rates seperately in each of the datasets, how do i pool over the incidence rates and get its 95% CI?
I tried to average the missing psychosocial factors first to get one single mean for the missingness and then calculate the incidence rates as a complete dataset. However, I feel that this method is wrong...
